# Function to reprogram muscle memory

Tags: spacemacs, keystrokes

I've switched from emacs to spacemacs, but my muscle memory still uses the standard emacs keybindings -- despite attempts at avoiding key chords.  As an example, to save a file, I continue to use `Ctrl` `x` `s` instead of `SPC` `f` `s`.

What I'd like is a function that would provide a modeline prompt for keystrokes that I'm trying to avoid.

"*`Ctrl` `x` `s` deprecated.  Use instead: `SPC` `f` `s`*"

---

*Update*: I used the function that [muffinmad](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9970/muffinmad) supplied with a minor tweak.  For some tasks my attention isn't focused on the modeline, so an additional audio alert helps:

```
    (play-sound-file "oops.wav")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") (lambda ()
                                  (interactive)
                                  (message "Ctrl x s deprecated. Use instead: SPC f s")))
```

`save-buffer` may be called while displaying deprecation message but doing so will reduce effectiveness. Just displaying deprecation message will force you to use new key binding.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Shouldn't this function try to execute whatever it was supposed to be bound to while displaying the deprecation warning?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 added note about effectiveness :)